# How to go to the cell whose value is written in an input box? (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I am pretty new to coding and while this should be relatively simple, I am stuck.

I have a bunch of columns, each showing data for a specific department that's denominated by a 6-digit code. I want to make an input box pop up to ask the user "Which Department would you like to see?" and then jump to the cell which has the appropriate number they enter.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: what have you tried so far? Suggest using `Application.Match` function or `Range.Find` method.

Comment: along these lines.... `anchorcell.offset(0,application.match(inputbox(),y,0)).activate`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav yes, but with error-handling if `Match` returns an error :)

Answer (score 0):

Press Alt+F11 and in the VBA editor and the name of the Worksheet where is located data that you analyze. Click the name of this sheet twice, a window (module) should open. Paste there the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim str As Range
    ans = InputBox("Which Department would you like to see?")
    With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:m500") 'determine the range 
    Set c = .Find(ans, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        Set str = Worksheets(1).Range(c.Address)
        str.Activate
        Exit Sub
    End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Every time you activate this worksheet, a pop-up window is going to appear.